# Set value from model in a label using html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have given view model.I have to set the value of Amount(which is getting retrieved from table using linq) on a label using Html helper.

```
 public class AllocationViewModel
        {   
           public long ID { get; set; }       
           public string Name { get; set; }        
           public double Amount { get; set; }
        }
```

Code for view page:--

```
@model Assetry.Controllers.AllocationViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Deal", FormMethod.Post))
  {
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Amount)
  }
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I have to show the value of amount on view in label form.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
 @model AllocationViewModel

 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Amount)
```

Comment: when I am using this then its showing label on which "Amount" is written but I want value of amount which is in database.

Comment: "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation" I am getting above error while using DisplayFor..:-(

Comment: Have you declared model like this? it seems like you have a untyped view.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the code you're trying with ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 @Html.Label(Model.Amount)
```

or
IF you want value in model,

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you don't need a display template, except you want to represent a double in a sophisticated manner using a template.

Try something like that (if you want to just display the amount):

```
<span>@Model.Amount</span>
```

To edit:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Amount)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)
```